# Change rendered display to show chart horizontally (x number of columns)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I've got a report in SSRS (I believe version 2014) that has a chart within a tablix as shown:

[image]

When I click "View Report" it shows like so:

[image]

Notice how it displays each chart (per detail) going down vertically.  Is there an easy way or property I could use to say display horizontally x number of columns.  So instead of one chart per row, show the next one right next to it...and so on horizontally until it hits the "x" number.  So it would show WP 10.45 then next to it the chart for WP 3.05 etc.

Comment: If it's only ever 3 charts.. you could make three tablix and filter each one to the relevant data and be done with it. If it is unknown number of charts.. then you can do the same.. but do a row_number with a Mod 3 and then filter each tablix to 0 1 and 2.. Hope that made sense

Comment: You could also look at splitting the reports into 3 columns (under Report properties - Columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: **I ended up copying the tablix and then setting a filter.**

**Technical Details**

For anyone else wanting to do this and needs a better explanation here is exactly what I did.

Remember the tablix I first created that I mentioned in my original question.
This one:

[image]

I went ahead and copied this entire tablix (as another tablix) and placed both of them on top of the **rectangle** object within Reporting Services.  They are the exact same tablix reports content:

[image]

Its hard to see but they are both on top of a rectangle object.  With that being said I then went to the properties of my tablix and went to the filters section:

[image]

Notice the expression, when I click the expression button this is the expression I have entered:

`=Fields!SortOrder.Value Mod 2`

Now you may be asking what the heck is `SortOrder`, well this is specific to my business case.  Each one of our "milestones" has a sort order associated with it.  We did not want to sort alphabetically because A-Z wouldn't matter.  We had to provide a column to ensure our milestones lined up correctly and this sort order in our table did this.

Now you may also be wondering why `Mod 2`.  Well only because we wanted to show 2 charts side by side.  If you wanted to show 3 charts you'd use `Mod 3` and copy the tablix 3 times.  If you wanted to show 4 charts you'd use `Mod 4` and copy the tablix 4 times, etc. etc.

By using `Mod 2` in my case in combination with the `SortOrder` (the `SortOrder` field is simply an integer).  I end up with a result of 0 (divides perfectly) or a value of 1 (I get a remainder).  Because of this my filter holds true since one of my `tablix` has a filter value of 0 and the other one has a filter value of 1, as shown:

[image]

The result is really nice...we end up with this:

[image]

Compare that to what I had originally in my question and you'll see how much better this actually is.  I could of also used the columns property in RS but this did not look so nice.